# Git - differences between commits for a specific file

Tags: git, logging, diff

I want to view all the differences between my old commits for a specific file.
What should be the command for it?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Are you looking for `git diff <SHA1> <SHA2> path/to/file`?

Answer (score 4):

This shows you changes to the file `/path/to/file` between `commit1` and `commit2`:

```
git diff <commit1_hash> <commit2_hash> -- /path/to/file
```

Comment: And in general, adding `-- /path/to/file` to the end of a git command performs the command on just that file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the history of changes for a specific file:

```
git log --follow -p path/to/file
```